# dynamically adjusting div size in an container by using CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I am adding div to a container dynamically based on the data. Please refer below image.

[image]

Currently in CSS width and height for DIV is fixed to 100%, because of this, added DIV are overflowing and not fitting in the parent container.  How can I achieve this by using only CSS.

Please have a look the below link

```
[enter code here][2]
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/w04uxbrf/)

Comment: Are you open to a jquery solution?

Comment: No :). is it possible to achieve by using CSS3